# How we can obtain Looker Reports Inventory for Free Version of Looker Studio

Tags: looker-studio, looker

My organization is currently using Looker’s free version, which comes with GCP. We are interested in finding out the number of Looker reports available in our cloud connected to Google BigQuery,  This will help us optimize our expenses.

I would appreciate it if someone could guide me on how to obtain this information. Please let me know if you require more details.